# pdoUpdate : decrease by 2 instead of 1

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo

I'm having a problem with a pdo execution. When i'm willing to decrease a field by 1, it is decreased by 2. Here is my code.

```
public static function majtrajetvalide($prot_id, $traj_type, $nombrepass) {

 //   var_dump($nombrepass); this dump returns int 1 . So the value is good.
    $query = "UPDATE dbo.TRAJET  SET TRAJ_NB_PLACE = TRAJ_NB_PLACE - $nombrepass  where PROT_ID = $prot_id and TRAJ_TYPE = '$traj_type'";

    return DataPdo::executeUpdate(
                    $query, array()
    );
 }
```

When i call this method, the field is decreased by 2. The fact is that my query has to be good because this one works in SQL server 2008 directly :

```
UPDATE dbo.TRAJET  SET TRAJ_NB_PLACE = TRAJ_NB_PLACE - 1 where PROT_ID = 59 and TRAJ_TYPE = 'A'
```

This query decrease by one, as i want.

So is there any problem with my pdo call? I don't see any reason why it would decrease by 2 instead of one. Maybe my function is running twice but I don't know if I can check it and i do'nt see why it would since I call it in the easiest way

Side note, i'm using sql server 2008.

EDIT : I found out that it works on google chrome. The bug is only on Internet Explorer 11. This is just going more weird...

Comment: Somehow you are calling the function two times.

Comment: Hum, as i just editted, it works on chrome but not on ie, i'm calling it only once :s